# MySQL Check if row contains value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check if a row in a MySQL table contains a value stored in another table.

This is what I am trying right now:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Column = '%');
```

This still finds rows which do contain the value in the second table. I have also tried exchanging EXISTS for LIKE and IN which both return syntax errors.

Edit:

Using the % Sign seems to cause an issue. Here are some screenshots of what happens when I use the percent sign:
[image]

One of the values stored in the second table is 'Meath', the row containing 'Meath' is still selected. If I add 'Meath' instead of '%' then the row isn't returned:
[image]

Comment: You need to specify a relation between the two tables.

Comment: What is the name of the column that you are checking between table1 and table2?

Comment: @Sam The column is called County, sorry I just put generic names for the example

Comment: Does this work? `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column2 FROM table2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
WHERE a.County NOT IN(SELECT County FROM table2)
```

This should match what you want.

Edit: if you need to only disregard certain values from table2, you could replace the second line with this

```
WHERE a.County NOT IN(SELECT County FROM table2 WHERE County IN('county1', 'county2'))
```

Comment: That works perfectly, can you just explain what the 'a' is, is it just a variable that could be any value?

Comment: You don't really need that, it's just a habit of mine. `FROM table1 a` makes `a` a kind of alias (I don't know the proper term) which you can use in the rest of your query. Where you see `a.County` that is the same as saying `table1.County`. It's helpful in queries that use tables that have the same column names.

Comment: Turns out it actually _is_ called an alias, haha. This might be helpful if my explanation wasn't: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))

Comment: Just another question is there anyway to do this and have % before and after the Selected County from table2? So that it doesn;t have to be exact

Comment: Yes! `NOT IN(SELECT County FROM table2 WHERE County LIKE '%county%')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some sort of relation between these two queries, for example

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table2 
                  WHERE Column = '%'
                    AND table1.Column = table2.Column);  --<-- Relate two queries
```

Each row returned from the Outer query will be checked for the condition you define in the where clause of the inner query, this relates the two queries else MySQL has no way of knowing how to check the existence of each row being returned by the outer query and it will return back nothing.

Comment: This still returns the rows that contain the values from the second table. Only when using the % sign though, if I change it to the specific value that the row has, then it doesn't show up, any thoughts?

Comment: @Edward144 Well explain what do you mean by rows that exist in the second table ? In other words how would you determine if a row exists in the second table or not ?

Comment: I've updated my post with screenshots to show what happens. I've confused myself a bit I think

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE column NOT IN (SELECT column FROM table2 
              WHERE Column = '%');
```